# Не могу понять где возникает ошибка

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться, в приложении закралась ошибка, выскакивает редко, у нескольких пользователей, в панели разработчиков вижу:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4532)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4496)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Но не могу понять даже на какую строку в коде ссылается эта ошибка, раньше с подобным не сталкивался.

Comment: у вас обработка нажатий случаем не через android:onclick в xml задается?

Comment: код выложите если не трудно

Comment: Да через android:onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое происходит, например, когда внутри фрагмента объявлен через xml обработчик клика. Обычно из-за того, что фрагмент еще не присоединен или *не совсем готов*

Вам нужно вычистить из своего лейаута `android:onclick` и декларировать обработчик нажатий через `View.OnClickListener`, в этом случае обработчик гарантированно сработает в нужный момент.

Comment: xml-атрибут `android:onClick` работает только для [разметки активити](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick)
 (точнее для контекста и его наследников), в фрагментах он не действует, так как фрагмент не наследник контекста, а так все правильно, конечно же :)